# Requesting help to convert an inline JS script to an external file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

With some help from user [enhzflep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630963/enhzflep), I now have a working script that does the following:

- Pulls data from [this Google Sheets API Callback](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData)
- Converts the data to a HTML table.
- Queries the data in column 1, and returns the result from the same row of column 2.

The code for this is:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spData = null;
  function doData(json) {
      spData = json.feed.entry;
  }
  
  function drawCell(tr, val) {
      var td = $("<td/>");
      tr.append(td);
      td.append(val);
      return td;
  }
  function drawRow(table, rowData) {
   if (rowData == null) return null;
   if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
   var tr = $("<tr/>");
   table.append(tr);
   for(var c=0; c<rowData.length; c++) {
    drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
   }
   return tr;
  }
  
  function drawTable(parent) {
   var table = $("<table/>");
   parent.append(table);
   return table;
  }
  
  function readData(parent) {
      var data = spData;
      var table = drawTable(parent);
      var rowData = [];
      
      for(var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
          var val = cell["$t"];
          if (cell.col == 1) {
              drawRow(table, rowData);
              rowData = [];
          }
          rowData.push(val);
      }
      drawRow(table, rowData);
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      readData($("#data"));
      searchTable( 'dragon', document.querySelector('table') );
  });

  function searchTable(searchStr, target)
  {
        let rows = Array.from( target.querySelectorAll('tr') );
        rows.forEach( (row,idx,col) => {
                                let firstCell = row.querySelector('td').textContent;
                                if (firstCell == searchStr)
                                {
                                      let cell2 = row.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent;
                                      console.log(`${searchStr} found in row ${idx}`);
                                      console.log(`col 2 of row #${idx} is: ${cell2}`);
                                }
                          }
                    );
  }


  </script>
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  form {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="data"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works perfectly when run as a webpage.

In this case, I'd like to embed the page to a Chrome Extension, to have the graph show on the Chrome Extension. The issue I'm having is that the script runs as an inline script, which isn't allowed as per the Chrome CSP. If I attempt it, understandably, the console logs the following errors:

```
callback.html:1
Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

callback.html:4
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

callback.html:1
Refused to load the script 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I was wondering if there was any way to instead have an external file alternative for the Google Sheet pull. I'm aware the ajax script issue can be resolved by including a local version of the `jquery.min.js` file in my Chrome Extension package, but I'm not sure if the same can be done for the other inline script.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: If the issue is loading external scripts, you could download them and include them in your package as static files.

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't be plausible for the use-case I have. The reason I have it as a Google Sheet instead of a local html table is because I need the table contents to be able to change without re-publishing the Chrome extension. If I save a copy of `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData`, the data will be static, and not automatically updated unless I download it again at a later date, then re-publish the Chrome Extension.

Comment: That is indeed the case with static filed that are embedded. The solution seems to be included in your error, "Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

Comment: The issue with this is that unsafe-inline is no logner allowed as per the [Chrome CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), and as it's linked a spreadsheet that can be edited, the nonce / SHA-256 hash could both become invalidated as soon as the sheet was updated, as the source code would change. This is the same reason I cannot download the file locally. I need to be able to update remotely.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I am calling your HTML file index.html and the file that I have moved the script to is called myScript.js which is in the same directory.

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./myScript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    form {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="data" />
</body>

</html>
```

myScript.js

```
var spData = null;

function doData(json) {
  spData = json.feed.entry;
}

function drawCell(tr, val) {
  var td = $("<td/>");
  tr.append(td);
  td.append(val);
  return td;
}

function drawRow(table, rowData) {
  if (rowData == null) return null;
  if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
  var tr = $("<tr/>");
  table.append(tr);
  for (var c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
    drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
  }
  return tr;
}

function drawTable(parent) {
  var table = $("<table/>");
  parent.append(table);
  return table;
}

function readData(parent) {
  var data = spData;
  var table = drawTable(parent);
  var rowData = [];

  for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
    var val = cell["$t"];
    if (cell.col == 1) {
      drawRow(table, rowData);
      rowData = [];
    }
    rowData.push(val);
  }
  drawRow(table, rowData);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  readData($("#data"));
  searchTable('dragon', document.querySelector('table'));
});

function searchTable(searchStr, target) {
  let rows = Array.from(target.querySelectorAll('tr'));
  rows.forEach((row, idx, col) => {
    let firstCell = row.querySelector('td').textContent;
    if (firstCell == searchStr) {
      let cell2 = row.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent;
      console.log(`${searchStr} found in row ${idx}`);
      console.log(`col 2 of row #${idx} is: ${cell2}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve the issue as the the index.html file still contains an inline script ( `<script
    src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData">
  </script>` ), which means it is not accepted by the Chrome CSP. Thank you for your assistance though.

Comment: That is not an inline script. There is an inline style tag, but that is different from a script. Have you tried this out?

Comment: I have tried it, and confirmed that it doesn't work. It it still treating `<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData">
  </script>` as a script, and [refuses to allow it to run](https://i.imgur.com/jKaQ90D.png). As that screenshot shows, the error is with "SO.html", which is [the exact HTML code you provided](https://i.imgur.com/lt0ppUk.png).

Comment: Okay, I just updated my answer. I added the following meta tag to allow for script src from external domains: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;">`.  Another, possibly better solution would be to download the jQuery and google spreadsheet script into your local directory and bypass the problem altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it [still will not allow the scripts](https://i.imgur.com/mdjaH5f.png). According to the [Chrome CSP Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), it appears there is no mechanism to relax the restriction against executing inline script, apart from using a hash. I'm not able to go down the method to download the Spreadsheet Script for the reasons mentioned in my comment on the original question (I need the sheet to be updated, being downloaded locally will prevent it from auto-updating). I can download the jQuery though. :)

Comment: hmmm very interesting. My very last idea is the following: download the jquery into your local directory then replace the meta tag I originally gave you and replace it with this one: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://spreadsheets.google.com; object-src 'self' ">`

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts, but it still doens't want to allow it. I downloaded and locally referenced jQuery, so that error is gone, but the script [still refuses to run](https://i.imgur.com/nX1CsFT.png). I appreciate you trying this for me though!